# Add a Browser UI button to a Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, manifest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm kind of a newbie. I made a Firefox WebExtension add-on.  It is very simple. The add-on changes words on the visited websites.

It has a manifest file that declares a content script.

My question is: How can I add a Browser UI button to the add-on?

Ultimately, my intent is to have the button allow the user to choose between seeing the website as delivered, or as modified by the the WebExtension. However, right now I'm just stuck on adding the button.

This is my *manifest.json*:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Gordo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "XXXXXX",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/img.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that my Answer does not fully answer the question which you have asked. The problem is that your question, as stated, is significantly too broad for this format. It is really *at least* three different questions: "How to add a button to the browser UI?" (this question), "How to make a browser UI button look and act like a toggle button?", and "How do I turn on and off changes my add-on is making to a webpage?". The last question is quite possibly/probably too broad in and of itself (because there are too many ways to do it).(continued)

Comment: (continued) Because this question is really too broad, I should have just voted to close rather than answer. I would suggest that you [edit] this question to be only about adding a UI button and [ask a new quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about how to make the button look and act like a toggle. Once you have an answer for that one, you could ask the third one. Depending on how the third one is worded, it might be answerable in this format. I'm contemplating how I would answer it. I'm thinking it might be glossed over in a single answer, but an in-depth answer would be too long.

Comment: If *any* answer (on any question, but particularly your own) was helpful, you should up-vote it. For your own questions, if someone has provided an answer which you used to answer your question, you [should accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Makyen While you make fair points, you also make assumptions (fair, but nonetheless) about what the button is intended to do.  That is probably another symptom of too broad a question.  It is probably the easiest thing to add a button which does nothing.  But a 4th (2nd, in order) question is to ask what the button is for?  Maybe a toggle, a context menu, a popup, a combination.  Maybe on/off, maybe open config, select new words to change, change style of changed words, etc.  But the basic question, to add a button, no action defined so no action taken, is fairly clear and simple, no?

Comment: @user314159, Yes, it's helpful to know more. It's possible the OP was wanting something else. However, for a WebExtension, there are only two types of "Browser UI button": Browser Action buttons and Page Action buttons. Yes, you can add a menu selection to a context menu, add an options page (which adds a button to open it from *about:addons*), add a button to a popup (normally opened with a Browser, or Page Action), or even add a button to an in-page, add-on UI (and now you can also have a UI in a sidebar). However, *none* of those are considered to be adding a button to the "Browser UI".

Comment: @user314159, It appears I removed some text from the original version of the question which, if re-worded, provides some of the context you're looking for. I removed the text because, as it was worded, it made the question too broad. I did this, rather than voting to close, because I felt having a question about "how to add a Browser UI button" would be helpful to future readers. I hoped the OP would post additional questions, with more context, for the further issues, as suggested in prior comments. I've edited the text back in, which is fine reworded to just provide some additional context.

Comment: wrt. The desire to have a toggle button: In my answer to [In a Firefox WebExtension, how I can make a button that looks and acts like a toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40604386) I provide a generalized solution to having multi-state buttons. The simplest case of a multi-state button is a toggle button (a button with two states).

Answer (score 1):

WebExtensions can add a browser UI button as either a Browser Action and/or a Page Action. You can have a maximum of one of each. For each, you can either have a button which code in your background script responds to (receives a `click` event), or the browser with show an HTML file you provide as a popup. You can set a default as to showing a popup, or getting a click. You can dynamically switch between the two by using `setPopup()` (setting to '' causes the `click` to fire; any other string and the referenced HTML file is used as the popup which is shown without triggering a `click` event).

### Browser Action

You can add a button to the browser user interface by adding a [`browser_action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action) key to your *manifest.json*:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "myIcon.png",
    "default_title": "Do my thing",
    "browser_style": true
}
```

You can then add a listener in your background script.  However, you first have to have a background script.  You can have one by adding a `background` key to your *manifest.json*:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
}
```

Then, in *background.js* you can add a listener for the button click by using [`browserAction.onClicked.addListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //Do what you want to do when the browser UI button is clicked.
});
```

### Page Action

Alternately, instead of using a browser action, you can use a page action.  The keys in the *manifest.json* and usage in your background script are very similar:

In your *manifest.json* use [`page_action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action):

```
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": "myIcon.png",
    "default_title": "Do my thing",
    "browser_style": true
}
```

Then, in *background.js* you can add a listener for the button click by using [`pageAction.onClicked.addListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/onClicked)

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //Do what you want to do when the browser UI button is clicked.
});
```

[MDN says the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action) about page actions:

> Page actions are like browser actions, except that they are associated with particular web pages rather than with the browser as a whole. If an action is only relevant on certain pages, then you should use a page action and display it only on relevant pages. If an action is relevant to all pages or to the browser itself, use a browser action.
>
> While browser actions are displayed by default, page actions are hidden by default. They can be shown for a particular tab by calling [`pageAction.show()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/show), passing in the tab's ID.

### Showing a popup

You can have the default be to show a popup by adding a `default_popup` key to either the `browser_action` key, or the `page_action` key.  The above `browser_action` could look like the following with a popup:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "myIcon.png",
    "default_title": "Do my thing",
    "browser_style": true
    "default_popup": "myPopup.html"
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me try to re-do all the code and then I let you know. I get so confuse and mix it up all

Comment: Ok, here my manifest.jason [link] https://github.com/rafael1138/Gordo-Comunista/blob/master/Working%20Next%20Update/manifest.json

Comment: Here thebackground.js [link] https://github.com/rafael1138/Gordo-Comunista/blob/master/Working%20Next%20Update/background.js

Comment: I can't get this work. (sorry I dont know how post code here, I tried every combination I know and nothing)

Comment: The *manifet.json* file works by itself (with a blank background.js) and valid icon files. I have not looked at/tried you *background.js* file yet. Doing that now.

Comment: Your *background.js* has a few issues. You use a `case` statement without a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). You will need a way to be checking against `'turn-on'` and `'turn-off'` (I personally use the button's title, which I change along with the other properties to indicate the state of the button (or actually the title I use to indicate to the user what the action will be when the button is pressed, which is the next state)). If using a popup, it is an HTML file, not JS. If you set a popup file, you will not get a click event.

Comment: So I have to change the popup.js to html in the background.js right?

Comment: I really apreciate if you can help me with this

Comment: For what you appear you are wanting to do, you should not be setting a popup at all. What you are generally doing in your code indicates you want to do this without using a popup. Thus, don't set the popup. We are rapidly getting beyond what would normally be done in comments. As I mentioned, in my comments on your question, you should really ask another question about how to make a button that looks and acts like a toggle. If you do, I can/will provide complete code for a browser button that is a toggle.

Comment: Thanks I appreacite you help

Comment: @rafael1138, I'm happy to help. If you do make another question, please leave me a comment, including `@Makyen` in the comment (and a link to the new question), so I am notified that it exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603655/in-a-firefox-webextension-how-i-can-make-a-button-that-looks-and-acts-like-a-tog