# Chrome Extension - show dynamic text on mouse hover over extension icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've recently built a popup chrome extension([Popup Notes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-notes/pakngoacmndjaomplokegbepmohpfofb))
It basically takes notes of whatever you type in popup.

Now I want to show saved notes whenever I hover my mouse over the extension icon.
Right now it shows the static default title on mouse hover.

I know it's possible because this extension [Checker Plus for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj) shows the unread emails content on mouse hover and I'm not able to figure out how.

See Image:
[image]

So, How Can I show popup content on hovering mouse over icon in chrome extension?

Let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For manifest V2 or earlier**: `chrome.browserAction.setTitle`

**For Manifest V3**: Use `chrome.action.setTitle`

The tooltip which is shown on hover for your `browserAction` button is the title.  You can change the title using `chrome.browserAction.setTitle()`.

For example:

```js
chrome.browserAction.setTitle({
    title:'This is the tooltip text upon mouse hover.'
});
```

`browserAction.setTitle()` can also take an optional `tabId` which will change the title only for the specified tab.

Here is a GIF of a `browserAction` button switching between two different titles:

[image: browserAction button switching between two different titles]

Comment: how to set it on hover? is there any hover event for this?

Comment: @JerryGoyal, There is no hover event available. You just set the title, then when the mouse hovers the button, the title is displayed (just like a tooltip is displayed without you having to do anything but set it). [Here is a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbNW4.gif) which shows a slight change in title. That GIF no longer exactly matches the code shown in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40604386/3773011). The code in that answer is to have buttons with multiple states. While that question is about Firefox WebExtensions, the code is tested in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: but the content is changed whenever user enters something but hover shows the content which I initially set. Do i have to call setTitle each and every time?

Comment: @JerryGoyal, You have to call `browserAction.setTitle()` any time you want the title to change. I'm not sure why/how it would be any different than that.