# Change Color Of SVG toolbar icon in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an extension for Firefox 57+ using WebExtensions.  I would like to change the color of the toolbar icon to indicate extension status.

I understand how, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869497/change-the-button-of-a-firefox-webextension-into-a-textstring) I could simply use `browserAction.setIcon()` to change the icon and substitute an icon with a different color.

I want to know if I really need to include icon-black.svg, icon-red.svg etc.. files in my extension or if there is some way I can simply load a single icon.svg file and use javascript to change the color of the image.  I was hoping I could somehow load it programmatically and modify the color of the svg (i.e. all paths) before passing it to `browserAction.setIcon()`.  Do I need to somehow load it into some kind of canvas type element to do this?  Can I even do this in an extension?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can do this in an extension

The [`browserAction.setIcon()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setIcon) states that the Object which is [passed to the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setIcon#Parameters) will contain either a `path` to the icon file within your extension (or an Object containing multiple such paths with different sizes), or an `imageData`, which is a [`browserAction.ImageDataType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/ImageDataType), which is an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) (or an Object specifying multiple such items with different sizes):

> The `ImageData` interface represents the underlying pixel data of an area of a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) element. It is created using the [`ImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) constructor or creator methods on the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) object associated with a canvas: [`createImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData) and [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). It can also be used to set a part of the canvas by using [`putImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData).

Such `CanvasRenderingContext2D` can use an [`SVGImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGImageElement) as a source to draw an image using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

So, yes, you can do this in an extension. And, yes, you need to load it into a "canvas type element" to do it.

### It's easier to change the icon badge text and color

It would be much simpler to use a icon badge and change the [background color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeBackgroundColor) and [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText) of the badge. Doing so might make for a better UX, as icon badges are the UI element specifically intended to transmit such sate-change information to users. You should also change the [badge title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setTitle) to indicate what the next click on the icon will do.

### Changing *only* the color is bad UI design

Changing just the color of an icon to indicate state is not a good user interface design. Doing so makes using the interface difficult for anyone with less than perfect vision (e.g. color blind, using a screen reader, etc.). At an absolute minimum, you should change something distinctly visible (e.g. shape, badge text, etc.) other than just the icon color. This *should* also include some change which is also detected by screen readers.

As an example of what types of problems this causes, the following is a discussion of Stack Exchange's use of only changing the color of the achievements icon for some notifications: [Change the color of the "achievements" icon when it's highlighted (for users with Deuteranopia)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356382/change-the-color-of-the-achievements-icon-when-its-highlighted-for-users-wit)