# Firefox plugin listen to click on extension button

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a dark theme plugin compatible with every websites.

I'm trying to make the button of my plugin behave like an on/off switch for the current active tab.

---

### First attempt:

Here is what you can read from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action)

> If you supply a popup, then the popup is opened when the user clicks
> the button, and your JavaScript running in the popup can handle the
> user's interaction with it. If you don't supply a popup, then a click
> event is dispatched to your extension's background scripts when the
> user clicks the button.

So, I should receive a 'click' event, right?

**Manifest**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DarkTheme",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Create a dark theme for any webpage.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "dark.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "dark.png",
    "default_title": "DarkTheme"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "dark.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**dark.js**

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'))
```

**No event received.**

---

### Second attempt

I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action#example) that I should be using `browser.browserAction` instead. Let's try:

**dark.js**

```js
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => console.log('happened'));
```

**Nothing received...**

---

### Third attempt:

If you read the doc carefully, you realize that the click event seems to be sent only to background script. So here we go:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DarkTheme",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Create a dark theme for any webpage.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "dark.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "dark.png",
    "default_title": "DarkTheme"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "button.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "dark.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**button.js**

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'))
```

**I don't see any log...**

---

### Fourth attempt:

I found [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603655/how-i-can-make-a-browser-action-button-that-looks-and-acts-like-a-toggle) that suggest I should use executeScript.

Here id what I did:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DarkTheme",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Create a dark theme for any webpage.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "dark.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "button.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "dark.png",
    "default_title": "DarkTheme"
  }
}
```

```js
let disabled = false;
// On click, we disable the plugin
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tabId => {
  disabled = !disabled
  // This works
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: disabled ? '/light.png' : '/dark.png' });
  // This works
  if (disabled) return browser.tabs.reload()
  // This doesn't work.
  else browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    file: '/dark.js',
    allFrames: true,
  });
});
// This should run the script without waiting for the user to press the button, but it doesn't work either.
browser.tabs.executeScript(undefined, {
  file: '/dark.js',
  allFrames: true,
})
```

Loading the script this way doesn't seem to work. I receive no log from dark.js.

> tabId Optional
>
> ```
> integer. The ID of the tab in which to run the script.
>
> Defaults to the active tab of the current window.
> ```

---

### Remaining problems:

1. Loading the script on every web page as if it was in `content_scripts`
2. Load script when `disabled` is false.

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it!

Here is the manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DarkTheme",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Create a dark theme for any webpage.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "dark.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "button.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "dark.png",
    "default_title": "DarkTheme"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "dark.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the backgroung script:

```js
let disabled = false;
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  disabled = !disabled
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: disabled ? '/light.png' : '/dark.png' });
  if (disabled) return browser.tabs.reload(tab.id).then(() => {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: 'window.disabled = true;',
      allFrames: true,
    })
  })
  else browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'window.disabled = false;'
  }).then(() => {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      file: '/dark.js',
      allFrames: true,
    });
  })
});
```

In the `dark.js` script, you only have to do `if (window.disabled) return` before your code to disable your plugin.